# Как импортировать записи вордпресс?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток!
Вопрос вот в чём.
У клиента есть интернет магазин на вордпрессе, но это не woocommerce.
Все товара - это кастомные типы записей, кним добавленны поля acf.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заказчик хочет обновить свой сайт, сделать его по новому дизайну и т д, но свой оставить, т.е это должны быть 2-а разных сайта.
Подскажите, как мне выгрузить все товары(кастомные типы записи), что бы сохранить поля acf, и инфу в них(есть поля с вложениями pdf). Как перенести их на другой сайт, 5к записей....
Желательно что бы это был эксэль файл
Был бы это вукомерс вообще без проблем, а так сижу голову ломаю.
Мб можно сделать импорт\эксперт БД? Но сохранятся ли при этом все поля, изображения и файлы пдф? Плз подскажите! Уже несколько дней голову ломаю.

Answer (score 0):

У WordPress есть инструмент, называется WordPress Importer. Он поможет вам выгрузить, а потом загрузить все записи и страницы. Найти его можно в Инструменты > Импорт/Экспорт. Сохраняет в формат xml если мне память не изменяет.

Ну или же второй вариант, на этой же БД сделайте новый дизайн (поставьте новую тему или создайте свою собственную) и не нужно ничего и никуда переносить. Просто в новом дизайне используйте все те же кастомные поля

Вот в таком формате у вас сохраняются поля при импорте/экспорте. Эти данные хранятся в таблице wp_postmeta поэтому они обязано выгружаться.

```
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_calednar_date]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[field_5c6320061f44d]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[calendar_date]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[20190217]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
```

Comment: А стандартный WordPress Importer он разве значения acf сохраняет? Я тоже думаю предложить на этом же сайте сделать, но изначально он хотел 2-а разных сайта

Comment: Добавил в ответе пример